# VBA Word 2010: Batch Save As PDF including files in subfolder

Tags: vba, pdf, batch-processing

[this VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250722/vba-word-2010-batch-save-as-pdf-is-not-saving-all-formating-in-original) (obtained from other post in this forum) converts doc/docx files in a folder to pdf. I've been trying to modify it to include also files in subfolders...but my knowledge of VBA is very limited. Any hint/solution will be much appreciated!!. Thank you.

Comment: How is this linked to tag [tag:batch-file]? do you mean [tag:batch-processing] instead?

Comment: Yeah, that's an error. I've corrected it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code you refer to already includes processing for each file in the given folder.

I'd suggest you need to nest that loop inside a parent loop which iterates through all the folders in the main folder.

```
For Each oSubFolder in oFolder.SubFolders
    ' do the for each loop for files in oSubFolder here
Next oSubFolder
```

You'd still need a further instance of the `For Each oFile in oFolder` loop in order to pick up on any files within the original parent folder (as opposed to being in a subfolder).